# a column in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql

I have many users who are registered and I want to change a Money column everywhere the same. For example to set 100.000$ and each player will have this amount. Maybe someone knows the way how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is very basic SQL. To set everyone's money to $100,000:

```
UPDATE table SET money=100000;
```

Comment: I'm new on phpMyAdmin, can you tell me where this code I can write and how correctly to write this line (Column name: Money) (Table name: Users)

Comment: How on earth did you get a user system in place without knowing how to execute an SQL query? Please go read a basic SQL tutorial.

Comment: Please just answer how, I don't have much time.. Actually I have never used a code over the SQL :(

Answer (score 0):

you can use update query without using where ,this will update all columns once with the same value

```
$db->query("update table set money_column='100000'");
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$freeroam->query("update users set Money='100000'")' at line 1

Comment: you should read more about mysql to know how,when,where to write an sql stmt